# Returning multi result from stored procedure

Tags: c#, sybase

I have stored procedure 'sp_MyProcedure' that give me multi result,
but when I execute it from c# it retrive me one result 'one row' only
this is my code:

```
DataTable myTable = new DataTable();
string  CommandString= "sp_MyProcedure";
OdbcDataAdapter adapter = new OdbcDataAdapter(CommandString, _OdbcConnection);
adapter.Fill(myTable);
```

Is there any way to get all rows of result from the stored procedure

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if the Adapter supports .NextResult() like the dbDataReader does.  But you move to resultsets using the dbDataReader.

Here is a link:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.nextresult(v=vs.110).aspx